# GCD functions causing undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang, grand-central-dispatch

I'm using `dispatch_once` and `dispatch_async` in my code to handle singletons and concurrency, respectively.

The `dispatch_once` code isn't too complex:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static id sharedInstance;

    dispatch_once(&once, ^
                  {
                      sharedInstance = [self new];
                  });

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

As for the `dispatch_async`, it's just a block of code that executes inside the return of a Facebook API call (to ensure it gets executed on the main thread):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            [self.tableView setNeedsDisplay];
        });
```

When I compile my application for x86, it works fine and no errors come up. If I compile for x86_64 (64 bit), it throws up the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_NR__dispatch_async", referenced from:
      ___23-[SNFFeedTVC getPhotos]_block_invoke in SNFFeedTVC.o
  "_NR__dispatch_once", referenced from:
      +[SNFFacebook sharedInstance] in SNFFacebook.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The GCD code that I'm using is standard and nothing complex, so I have no idea why it wouldn't compile for this architecture. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: i would guess some of your third party libraries do not include a 64 bit slice. To check you can run command 'file aLibName.a' in the terminal to check what slices are present.

Comment: Fixed, I just got that `NR` = New Relic framework. Turns out they aren't 64 bit compatible yet, so I removed the framework.

Comment: Also fixed by removing New Relic framework.